# Unexpected php notice and warning when using array_filter

Tags: php

I am getting the following

> Notice: Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - assumed
>   'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH' in C:\projects\yada.php on line 88
>
> Warning: array_filter() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in
>   C:\projects\yada.php on line 88
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH - assumed
>   'ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH' in C:\projects\yada.php on line 91
>
> Warning: array_filter() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in
>   C:\projects\yada.php on line 91

The code is as follows

```
$unregistered_team_names = array_filter($data, function ($v, $k) {
    return strpos($k, 'unregistered_user_name_') !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
$unregistered_team_emails = array_filter($data, function ($v, $k) {
    return strpos($k, 'unregistered_user_email_') !== false;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

The code seems valid as per the documentation provided here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

THe callback never gets called.

Comment: Read changelog http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-changelog and check your php version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [changelog](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-changelog) section of `array_filter` manual:

> **5.6.0**    Added optional `flag` parameter and constants `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` and `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH`

So, the answer is: your php version is **lower** than `5.6`.

Comment: What if you have PHP 7.0.31 but still have this error message come up?

Comment: I suppose that your php is not 7.0.31.